# How to fetch id from url?

Tags: php, url

I want to fetch id from the url.

URL:- localhost/projects/PortalGrocery/development/admin/projects/home/edit/27

I have tried:-

```
    $update_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $path = parse_url($update_url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $pathComponents = explode("/", trim($path, "/"));
    $ID = $pathComponents[7];
```

It is working fine but when i upload my project on live site, i have  to change the component number everytime and in every controller as there is difference in no. of components.

So, I want to know if there is any other method to fetch to do so..?

Comment: `substr(strrchr($url, '/'), 1);`

Comment: Does your id always come at the end or it may come anywhere in the url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$id = substr(strrchr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'), 1);
```

This code extracts the part of the string after the last `/`

Comment: and in case of add , my id comes at the second last position.

url-localhost/projects/PortalGrocery/development/admin/projects/extensions/27/add

Comment: @abhishek02: Then try regular expressions: `~(\d+)(?:/add)?$~`

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of all this

```
$update_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$path = parse_url($update_url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$pathComponents = explode("/", trim($path, "/"));
$ID = $pathComponents[7];
```

You should  try the following trick

```
$ID = substr(strrchr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your id always come at the end, Zerkms solution will work

```
$id = substr(strrchr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'), 1);
```

Comment: why exact  duplicate answer ?

Comment: Well when I started posting ans, there was no answer to the question. By Zerkms solution, I mean solution in comment, not in ans

Answer (score 0):

you can do it the below way..

```
$update_url = "localhost/projects/PortalGrocery/development/admin/projects/home/edit/27";
$path = parse_url($update_url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$pathComponents = explode("/", trim($path, "/"));

echo $pathComponents[sizeof($pathComponents) - 1]; //gives 27
```